# DocuSign PHP: envelope with multiple documents

Tags: docusignapi

Using the PHP SDK, how do I create an envelope that includes multiple documents?

Do I just use multiple `\DocuSign\eSign\Model\Document` objects in my Envelopes::create call?

Answer (score 0):

This example PHP code creates an envelope that includes 3 documents.

```
/**
 * Creates envelope definition
 * Document 1: An HTML document.
 * Document 2: A Word .docx document.
 * Document 3: A PDF document.
 * DocuSign will convert all of the documents to the PDF format.
 * The recipients' field tags are placed using <b>anchor</b> strings.
 * @param $args parameters for the envelope:
 *              signer_email, signer_name, signer_client_id
 * @return mixed -- returns an envelope definition
 */
private function make_envelope($args)
{
    # document 1 (html) has sign here anchor tag **signature_1**
    # document 2 (docx) has sign here anchor tag /sn1/
    # document 3 (pdf)  has sign here anchor tag /sn1/
    #
    # The envelope has two recipients.
    # recipient 1 - signer
    # recipient 2 - cc
    # The envelope will be sent first to the signer.
    # After it is signed, a copy is sent to the cc person.
    #
    # create the envelope definition
    $envelope_definition = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeDefinition([
       'email_subject' => 'Please sign this document set'
    ]);
    $doc1_b64 = base64_encode($this->create_document1($args));
    # read files 2 and 3 from a local directory
    # The reads could raise an exception if the file is not available!
    $demo_docs_path = __DIR__ . '/../public/demo_documents/';
    $content_bytes = file_get_contents($demo_docs_path . $GLOBALS['DS_CONFIG']['doc_docx']);
    $doc2_b64 = base64_encode($content_bytes);
    $content_bytes = file_get_contents($demo_docs_path . $GLOBALS['DS_CONFIG']['doc_pdf']);
    $doc3_b64 = base64_encode($content_bytes);

    # Create the document models
    $document1 = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Document([  # create the DocuSign document object
        'document_base64' => $doc1_b64,
        'name' => 'Order acknowledgement',  # can be different from actual file name
        'file_extension' => 'html',  # many different document types are accepted
        'document_id' => '1'  # a label used to reference the doc
    ]);
    $document2 = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Document([  # create the DocuSign document object
        'document_base64' => $doc2_b64,
        'name' => 'Battle Plan',  # can be different from actual file name
        'file_extension' => 'docx',  # many different document types are accepted
        'document_id' => '2'  # a label used to reference the doc
    ]);
    $document3 = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Document([  # create the DocuSign document object
        'document_base64' => $doc3_b64,
        'name' => 'Lorem Ipsum',  # can be different from actual file name
        'file_extension' => 'pdf',  # many different document types are accepted
        'document_id' => '3'  # a label used to reference the doc
    ]);
    # The order in the docs array determines the order in the envelope
    $envelope_definition->setDocuments([$document1, $document2, $document3]);


    # Create the signer recipient model
    $signer1 = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Signer([
        'email' => $args['signer_email'], 'name' => $args['signer_name'],
        'recipient_id' => "1", 'routing_order' => "1"]);
    # routingOrder (lower means earlier) determines the order of deliveries
    # to the recipients. Parallel routing order is supported by using the
    # same integer as the order for two or more recipients.

    # create a cc recipient to receive a copy of the documents
    $cc1 = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\CarbonCopy([
        'email' => $args['cc_email'], 'name' => $args['cc_name'],
        'recipient_id' => "2", 'routing_order' => "2"]);

    # Create signHere fields (also known as tabs) on the documents,
    # We're using anchor (autoPlace) positioning
    #
    # The DocuSign platform searches throughout your envelope's
    # documents for matching anchor strings. So the
    # signHere2 tab will be used in both document 2 and 3 since they
    #  use the same anchor string for their "signer 1" tabs.
    $sign_here1 = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\SignHere([
        'anchor_string' => '**signature_1**', 'anchor_units' => 'pixels',
        'anchor_y_offset' => '10', 'anchor_x_offset' => '20']);
    $sign_here2 = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\SignHere([
        'anchor_string' => '/sn1/', 'anchor_units' =>  'pixels',
        'anchor_y_offset' => '10', 'anchor_x_offset' => '20']);

    # Add the tabs model (including the sign_here tabs) to the signer
    # The Tabs object wants arrays of the different field/tab types
    $signer1->setTabs(new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Tabs([
        'sign_here_tabs' => [$sign_here1, $sign_here2]]));

    # Add the recipients to the envelope object
    $recipients = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\Recipients([
        'signers' => [$signer1], 'carbon_copies' => [$cc1]]);
    $envelope_definition->setRecipients($recipients);

    # Request that the envelope be sent by setting |status| to "sent".
    # To request that the envelope be created as a draft, set to "created"
    $envelope_definition->setStatus($args["status"]);

    return $envelope_definition;
}
```